# View passed testcases and show log messages in html report when using python html-testrunner??

Tags: python, html, report, python-unittest

I just started using html-testrunner to create human readable reports for python tests. I have two questions.

1) I was wondering if it is possible to view PASSED testcases? Currently there is only option to check ERROR and FAILED ones.

2) Is there a way to log in HTML report? I was trying to use logger but it is visible only in console output, not html report output.

```
import HtmlTestRunner
import unittest
import os
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger("DummyLogger")

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
""" Example test for HtmlRunner. """

def test_upper(self):       
    """ Test where I put warning inside of it """
    log.info('Printing info inside test case')
    log.warning('Printing warn inside test case')
    self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

def test_isupper(self):
    self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
    self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

def test_split(self):
    s = 'hello world'
    self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
    log.info('Printing info inside test case')
    log.warning('Printing warn inside test case')
    # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        s.split(2)

def test_error(self):
    """ This test should be marked as error one. """
    raise ValueError

def test_fail(self):
    """ This test should fail. """
    log.info('Printing info inside test case')
    log.warning('Printing warn inside test case')
    self.assertEqual(1, 2)

@unittest.skip("This is a skipped test.")
def test_skip(self):
    """ This test should be skipped. """
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stderr )
logging.getLogger( "DummyLogger" ).setLevel( logging.INFO )
  unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='outputFolder', report_title='Dummy report title test'))
```

I am hoping someone can help me on this one...

Comment: can you change this line logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stdout )?

Comment: I just changed it. No changes.