# Python - How to log records to both console and stdout

Tags: python, logging, stdout

I'm trying to replace all *print* statements from the old test framework with Python *logging*.
I need to use a simple *logging.debug('something')* way to write records to both console and test report.
I'm using a custom logger for each test module like this:

logger.py

```
import logging
from sys import stdout


def setup_logger(filename):
    logger = logging.getLogger(filename)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
    logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
    
    return logger
```

test_file.py

```
from logger import setup_logger
logger = setup_logger(__name__)    
logger.debug('something')
```

Currently I can write to the console but I don't see those records in sys.stdout when I'm generating test reports. I'm using **HtmlTestRunner** for generating test reports and it looks like it doesn't receive stdout records from tests here:

```
self._stdout_data = sys.stdout.getvalue()
```

https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/blob/master/HtmlTestRunner/result.py#L181

I'm not very familiar with logging and I don't understand what might be an issue here.

Is *sys.stdout* something completely different from the stdout where my custom logger writes messages?
Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

I read other similar questions about this (so my custom logger was written after reading those) but my issue is a bit different as I'm using the report generator which is parsing sys.stdout.

**UPD:** Or maybe I'm already doing this right but I need to read not the sys.stdout but something else to find my records when generating test report?

**UPD2:** Found a similar old question which was never answered) Maybe there's no quick solution for that(
[View passed testcases and show log messages in html report when using python html-testrunner??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275403/view-passed-testcases-and-show-log-messages-in-html-report-when-using-python-htm)

Comment: `HTMLTestRunner` generates just `html` file with results. Could you explain what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, I think your `UPD:` is right.  You shouldn't be trying to read from sys.stdout, ever, I don't think.  To do it the way you are trying to, would need to exec your script from another script and then read the stdout.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I want to solve 2 problems:
1) add records from tests to console (currently there are only print statements which are only seen in the test result report but are not seen in the console);
2) get rid of "print()" statements in the code

Comment: @Cargo23 this is what HtmlTestRunner does (reads from sys.stdout, see https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/blob/master/HtmlTestRunner/result.py#L181 ). And it works with "print()" but I don't see any records when I replace "print()" with "logging.debug". That's what I'm trying to solve...

Comment: @Medvedscak don't understand ))) could you add a one test and how you run it?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar it's used for some test actions. So the reason is that print() is a bit weird there + I don't want to add duplicates (in order to see the same records in console). These are GUI tests so it's useful to see steps in the console (i.e. during/after the build is run) + test report has those records too. It doesn't matter what the test is - the use is pretty simple. Tests used to have print('I did something') but I want to change it to log.debug('I did something'). The idea is that I need this debug record both in console and the resulting report

Comment: @Medvedscak how you run tests? `docker container`? `bash`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar it's a docker container which basically uses HtmlTestRunner for running unittests and creating reports. The code is old so many weird things are there. The thing I don't understand is why logging records cannot be found in sys.stdout. As I see, the HtmlTestRunner uses stream from unittest here: https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/blob/master/HtmlTestRunner/runner.py#L16

I remind that there are no issues with print() statements, they appear in sys.stdout here: https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/blob/master/HtmlTestRunner/result.py#L181

Comment: @Medvedscak oooh... docker container... by the way I asked [how you run tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518973/python-how-to-log-records-to-both-console-and-stdout?noredirect=1#comment124661723_70518973) before my answer.

for the future. no one can help you until you:
1) show at least 1 test
2) show how you run tests
3) show actual + expected output / stdout / stderr.

why? because no one can reproduce your behaviour.
jfyi: I think your problem is not related to `HtmlTestRunner` or `python logging`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar I don't get why it can be important) I pointed the line of the HtmlTestRunner and where it gets the prints. It doesn't matter how and where those tests are running, it's a usual unittest which has a print() statement. The issue is that it's not possible to make it see logging records. Though it can see prints. Yes, the issue is not in the testrunner itself as it basically uses unittest. And it looks like nobody solved it as it's probably much easier just to switch to some allure )

Comment: @Medvedscak you can point 1000+ lines of HtmlTestRunner(or logging, or something else) it's useless because you are trying to find a problem where there is no problem.
All this situation looks like `a problem on a host but I trying to find and fix the problem on a local machine + on different environment` 

Comment: @Medvedscak `It doesn't matter how and where those tests are running` never say that again  just be sure

Comment: @DanilaGanchar sorry but it looks like you just didn't understand my question. Which is quite simple - how can someone use logging to replace the print() - aka write to stdout - AND read this stdout later to use it in generating test report. I haven't worked with this before so I don't really know how all these streams work. Maybe there are several stdouts and I'm writing not where I need.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar in my case docker container doesn't change anything as I'm running and debugging from inside of it. So no this env issue

Comment: @Medvedscak yes-yes... ))) I say [one more time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70518973/python-how-to-log-records-to-both-console-and-stdout?noredirect=1#comment124663628_70518973)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the only good way to solve such an issue is writing a function which does 2 things: adds logs to console (I ended up with just using loguru - simple and clear) and prints the same message (the only purpose of that is to support old test reports). Of course it might look weird that someone needs output data in success reports as well but it's not my personal choice)